# Manually add an exe to Programs and Features in control panel

Tags: windows, vb.net, registry, regedit, controlpanel

I'm currently working on a program written in Microsoft Visual Basic. I made a custom installer for it, however, it does not add anything to the Programs and Features list.

I'm trying to figure out what keys I need to manually edit using regedit, so that way I know what I need to add to the code.

Comment: Are you asking for what keys to create, or are you asking how to create the keys?

Comment: @Hursey I'm asking what keys I need to create.

Comment: Well, MHO is why bother with all the different deployment tools already available,  however if you're committed to this, you could always use one of these deployment tools and see what keys it makes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write values under `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\YourAppnameOrGuid`

`DisplayName` and `UninstallString` are required, [the others are optional](https://web.archive.org/web/20110707025902/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa372105).